# cannot retrieve full text with doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

i'm trying to retrieve a json string from a column defined as longtext (mysql). I defined the Symfony entity with the following annotation:

```
@ORM\Column(type="text")
```

The string in the db is 6880 characters long, but it retrieves only the first 6725.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would it work if you used `type="mediumtext"` in the column definition, or `longtext` to match the column definition?

Comment: Could you try "json" doctrine type? Alternatively, I would try "blob" doctrine type and count bytes read from resource, just to investigate what will happen.
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#blob

Comment: At PHP level text type is just a string so it can certainly be longer than 6880 chars - what is the mysql definition for your column?